# Why is the Voltage across a Inductor not equal to 0 when the switch is closed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

[image]

I have such a diagram and at time t = 0 the switch closes, need to calculate the voltage across an inductor.I know that the Current across the inductor is 0 But the voltage across the inductor is not 0 but -120. But that does not follow ohms law  V = IR, So I'm trying to figure out why this is

Comment: why do you expect the *inductor* to follow Ohm's law?

Comment: Yea, I saw a post saying its not a "ohmic device",not sure what that means tho

Comment: Different circuit elements have different voltage - current relatoinships. A resistor is defined by Ohm's law: $v=Ri$. The voltage of an inductor follows Faraday's Law: $v = L\frac{di}{dt}$ see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor .  A capacitor is defined by $i = C\frac{dv}{dt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inductor is not an ohmic device that is it does not follow $V= IR$.

It instead follows equation $V = L\frac{dI}{dt}$,
Since

Just when switch is closed $I$ is instantaneously $zero$ , it has started increasing this change in current leads to potential difference across inductor
Hope it helps

Comment: Why the negative sign? If the current is increasing, the port of the inductor which conventional current enters will be the high potential port. Also, there must be zero voltage across the resistor which means the port of the inductor closest to the resistor must be +V relative to ground, and conventional current is increasing to the right.

Comment: Some one did edit I didn't realise thanks I will change it

Comment: I think the negative sign should be there because when the current increases in the circuit, the inductor acts as if it is opposing the change in current by acting as a battery of opposite polarity. When the current increases the inductor will act as a battery where the voltage drop will be -ve(+ve termial of induc. with +ve of battery)and when the current is decreasing it will boost up the current(in order for the current to not change, or not let it decrease) and act as a battery with +ve voltage drop and the -ve terminal of the inductor will be connected to the -ve of the actual battery.